# How can I switch back from KDE to Cinnamon modifying some Ubuntu configuration files

Tags: kde, desktop-environments, cinnamon, arm, arm64

I've installed KDE full on my Jetson Nano, but I made a huge mistake. On the screen I see the error `failed to start kernel modules` and it gets stuck before to show the login screen (I'm using an HDMI monitor attached); so nothing works and I don't know what I can do to switch back to my previous desktop manager, Cinnamon, which worked great. What I think I can do is to remove the SD card, change some parameters in the proper config files,but I don't know what files could be. Can someone of you point me to the right direction? I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. Thanks.

Comment: You flagged arm? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/jetson-nano-sd-card-image

Comment: WHAT!! How is that the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   Ubuntu is downloaded from ubuntu.com (applies to Ubuntu *flavors* too, ie. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ )

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: You need to restore configuration files, but you don't know which, and you don't have backups. Unfortunately, you may need to reinstall the OS.  In the future if you want to try a new DE, I suggest to boot a live session from installation media.  Changing the DE on an installed system is a huge undertaking and it's not simple to just switch back.